# How to use and validate an existing 3rd party type with Zod?

Tags: typescript, geojson, zod

I am convering types in an old project to Zod types. I have previously defined some types such that some of their properties come from an external library GeoJson.

```js
interface SomeInterface {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  point: GeoJson.Point;
}
```

Now here the `point` is causing me problems. I could try to redo the zod schema from the GeoJson definitions, but I would have to do that for every single type that I have and that uses something from GeoJson. Is there some way to convert these types to Zod and parse the data against them?

Comment: [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-to-zod) looks pretty cool but I don't know if it follows references to other types.

Comment: Tried it out and it simply skips types that are dependent of external libraries

Answer (score 0):

You may try this solution ([link](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/52#issuecomment-629897855) to original post):

```
const 3rdPartyType: z.ZodType<3rdPartyType> = z.any();

const FullSchema = z.object({ 
  foo: z.string(), 
  bar: 3rdPartyType,
});
```

Comment: An identifier may not start with a number.